# The topology of the classifying space of U(n)

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces

In $\textit{Atiyah and Bott: The Yang-Mills equations over riemann surfaces}$, there is a sentence about the topology of BU(n) (i.e. the classifying space of U(n)):

[image: Atiyah-Bott]

Here $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ means the Eilenberg-MacLane space with the $n^{th}$ homotopy group $\mathbb{Z}$. Does anybody know what's the meaning of the symbol ${\simeq \atop \mathbb{Q}}$? Does anyone know a reference (or a proof) for the statement? Thanks a lot!

Comment: My guess is that there is a natural map, say $f$ in one direction such that $\pi_n(f)$ is an isomorphism after tensoring with the rationals. In otherwords, the two spaces become equivalent once you localize the category of topological spaces at 0. I could be wrong though

Comment: Standard: rational homotopy equivalence, meaning the two spaces become homotopy equivalent after rationalizing (when the Z's become Q's on the right).  A suitable map from left to right is given by the Chern classes.

Comment: Pages 163ff of Griffiths-Morgan. http://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/GM81.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Griffiths and Morgan, *Rational Homotopy Theory and Differential Forms* (see nsrt's comment above):

> $\mathrm{BU}(n)$ is the Grassmannian of $n$-planes in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$. Recall that $$\mathrm{H}^\ast(\mathrm{BU}(n),\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}[c_1,\cdots,c_n]$$
>   Where $c_i\in\mathrm{H}^{2i}(\mathrm{BU}(n),\mathbb{Z})$ is the $i$th Chern class of the universal vector bundle. This gives a map $$\mathrm{BU}(n)\xrightarrow{f}\prod^n_{i=0}K(\mathbb{Z},2i)$$
>   Which induces an isomorphism on $\mathbb{Q}$-cohomology.